Convert color bitmap to pf8bit grayscale
I want to convert an image to grayscale. The result must be pf8bit.
With this code, the result looks fine (and gray indeed), but if I uncomment the last line, the result gets a bit grabbled like when you convert a high color image to 256 color GIF.
function CreateGrayPalette(NumColors: Integer= 256): HPALETTE;
VAR
  i  : Integer;
  lp : TMaxLogPalette;
  Grey: Byte;
begin
  lp.palVersion := $300;
  lp.palNumEntries := NumColors;
  for i := 0 to NumColors - 1 do
   begin
     Grey := i * 255 DIV NumColors;
     lp.palPalEntry[i].peRed   := Grey;
     lp.palPalEntry[i].peGreen := Grey;
     lp.palPalEntry[i].peBlue  := Grey;
     lp.palPalEntry[i].peFlags := PC_RESERVED;
   end;
  Result := CreatePalette(pLogPalette(@lp)^);  // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createpalette
end;


procedure SetBitmapGrayPalette(BMP: TBitmap);
begin
  VAR GrayPalette := CreateGrayPalette;
  if GrayPalette <> 0
  then BMP.Palette:= GrayPalette;
end;
{$R-}

function RGB2Gray(Color: TColor): TColor;
CONST
  LuminanceR = 54;   // Luminance multipliers
  LuminanceG = 184;
  LuminanceB = 18;
VAR
  Luminance: Byte;
begin
  Luminance :=
    (((Color AND $00FF0000) SHR 16 * LuminanceR) +
     ((Color AND $0000FF00) SHR 8  * LuminanceG) +
     ((Color AND $000000FF)        * LuminanceB)) SHR 8;

  Result := (Color and $FF000000) OR (Luminance SHL 16) OR (Luminance SHL 8) OR Luminance;
end;

procedure ConvertToGrayscale(BMP: TBitmap);
begin
  // Desaturate (works!)
  BMP.PixelFormat:= pf32bit;
  for var Row := 0 to BMP.Height-1 do
  begin
    var Line:= PDword(BMP.ScanLine[Row]);
    var Col := BMP.Width;
    WHILE Col > 0 DO
    begin
      Line^ := RGB2Gray(Line^);
      Inc(Line);
      Dec(Col);
    end;
  end;

  // And set the palette to gray
  SetBitmapGrayPalette(BMP);

  // This reduces the no of colors but does not make it gray.
  //BMP.PixelFormat:= pf8bit;
end;
{$R+}


You should tell us what RGB2Gray and SetBitmapGrayPalette are.

I'll hazard a guess that RGB2Gray is setting R=G=B = xR+ yG + z*B in 24 bit colour mode. You then need to compress the line down to BMP.Width monochrome Y bytes not BMP.Width RGB tuples. There are also rules about rounding lines to the nearest multiple of 4 at end of line. There are too many hidden functions to make more than an educated guess...

Using your code, and uncommenting the BMP.PixelFormat:= pf8bit; line shows a perfect (in my mind) grayscale image of the original color image. Please add sample images to your post.

procedure ConvertBitmapTo8Bit(const ABitmap: TBitmap);
var tempjpeg: TJPEGImage;
begin
    if Assigned(ABitmap) then
    begin
        if (not ABitmap.Empty) then
        begin
            tempjpeg := TJPEGImage.Create;
            try
                tempjpeg.CompressionQuality := c100;
                tempjpeg.Assign(ABitmap);
                tempjpeg.JPEGNeeded;
                tempjpeg.PixelFormat := jf8bit;
                tempjpeg.Grayscale := true;
                tempjpeg.DibNeeded;
                ABitmap.Assign(tempjpeg);
                ABitmap.PixelFormat := pf8Bit;
            finally
                tempjpeg.Free;
            end;
        end;
    end;
end;


This does a destructive (lossy) compression of the original image.

@HeartWare - at least the quality is set to maximum :) :) But it would be interesting to see how much quality it looses. I guess not that much.

@IceCold: Yes - just wanted to make sure to mention that it still is lossy compressed, even at quality 100 (which some people might believe would lead to lossless).

The code using JPEG produces much better result especially with gradient bitmaps. Check against your routine.

Jpeg2K supports lossless compression. Too bad that format never took flight!
